# Displaying latitude and longitude values in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to display latitude and longitude values in a `TextView`, but while running the project the values are not displayed. Can anyone help me?,Thank you in advance. My code is below:
 **GeocodingActivity.class**

```
public class GeocodingActivity extends Activity {
LocationManager locman;
Criteria cri;
LocationProvider locpro;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
Handler handler;
TextView t1;
LocationListener loclis;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    locman=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
       handler=new Handler(){
        public void handle(Message msg){
                  switch(msg.what){
        case 1: 
            t1.setText((String)msg.obj);
            break;
        }

        }
loclis=new LocationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Message.obtain(handler, 1,   arg0.getLatitude()+","+arg0.getLongitude()).sendToTarget();

}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
Bundle extras) {
     }
    };


}

}
```

Comment: Finally i got the output ,just i added the requestLocationupdate method and renamed the handle method to handleMessage then relocated the LocationListener class outside the onCreate method ,now it works fine,thanks for all those who helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Message.obtain(handler,0,location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude()).sendToTarget();
```

So you must realize that both methods `getLongitude` and `getLatitude` returns `Double`. And you need `String`.
So you need to convert them to `String` with method `String.valueOf()`

```
Message.obtain(handler, 0, String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + "," + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude())).sendToTarget();
```

Then, `Message.obj` returns `Object` so for getting `String` from there you should cast it to `String` so `t1.setText((String) msg.obj);`

Now, it should works.

---

**EDIT:**

**Second approach**

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   String data = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + "," + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
   bundle.putString("updateGpsData", data);
   yourMessage.setData(bundle);
   yourMessage.obtain(handler, 0).sendToTarget();
```

}

Then your `handle` method can looks like this

```
public void handle(Message msg){
   t1.setText(msg.getData().getString("updateGpsData"));
}
```

So you can create `Bundle` and your updated data just add to `Bundle` and then with `setData()` you set data for your `Message` and in handle method you call `getData().getString()` for retrieve your update `GPS` data.

Don't forget that `Bundle` works on pair **key + value** so you set data to your `Bundle` with specific key so for get data you have to use **same key** ("updateGpsData").

Comment: there is no setData method for Message (i.e,yourMessage)in your case

Comment: setData is not static method, you should call it with instance so Message message; message.setData()...

Comment: i updated the code ,no result .can u check MyCode i edited it

Comment: so problem is elsewhere,Handler is generally used with Threads and you don't have Thread, have look at some tutorials with Handler. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316393/handler-looper-implementation-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

please use the `String.valueOf` method on your coordinates like this

```
String.valueO(location.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude())
```

Comment: it shows error ,i think double value cannot be converted to string

Comment: why you don't ""+(location.getLatitude()) to convert into String!!?